# I am unable to perform the vector embeddings with the help of pinecone and python

Tags: langchain, word-embedding, huggingface, py-langchain, pinecone

I have done chunking of the data prior to this and intend to do embeddings and store in pinecone. I have reffered youtube on this as well and found this code and its not working.

```
docsearch = pc.from_documents([t.page_content for t in text_chunks], embeddings, index_name= 'mcahtbot')
```

I get this error.

```
AttributeError: 'Pinecone' object has no attribute 'from_documents'
```

Reffered to pinecone, youtube and searched other platforms for answers to similar problem

Comment: Can you include the code that you used to define the `pc` variable?

Comment: You might need to use a PineconeVectorStore rather than a Pinecone object. See https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/vectorstores/pinecone for an example.

Comment: Continue the recommendation from @nickodell, the code >  `docsearch = PineconeVectorStore.from_documents([t.page_content for t in text_chunks], embeddings, index_name= 'mcahtbot')`